# Create Vertical Sine wave

Tags: java, waveform, sine-wave

I am developing a game which uses sine wave.
I made use of the horizontal sin wave with the following example
http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/create_sine_wave.shtml

How do create a similar kind of wave vertically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where it says

```
g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

swap the order of x and y values.

Comment: Had to wait 5 minutes for doing it.. Done

Answer (score 3):

Try swapping the X and Y coordinates

Answer (score 2):

You can easily swap the values of x and y.
This will result in changing the graph coordinates hence if its horizontal before it'll become vertical and vice verse.